# When writing to a CSV file, previous string is overwritten

Tags: java

I am trying to make a simple program that saves user input on a swing form to a .CSV file.  I have it working to where it will write the first time.

If I exit out or enter a second set of values, and click save the previous string is overwritten in the file.

```
            try {
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("customer.csv"));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                sb.append(merch);
                sb.append(',');
                sb.append(cont);
                sb.append(',');
                sb.append(mail);
                sb.append(',');
                sb.append(cphone);
                sb.append('\n');

                pw.write(sb.toString());
                pw.flush();
                pw.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "File Not     Located");
                e1.printStackTrace();
```

I tried adding the 'sb.append('\n');' to the end thinking that would fix it, but it did not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open file in append mode:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("customer.csv", true));
```

Comment: that fixed it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file.txt", true)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8, you might want to clean it up like so:

```
    try(Writer pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("customer.csv", true)))) {
        pw.write(new StringJoiner(",", "", "\n")
            .add(merch)
            .add(cont)
            .add(mail)
            .add(cphone)
            .toString()
        );
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "File Not Located");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```